# Swift Как отформатировать текст по примеру?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

Подскажите, как можно так же отформатировать текст (зеленые подзаголовки) в ячейке TableViewController как примере №1, хочу применить в своем приложении (Фото 2)

[image: Пример 1]

[image: Пример 2]

Comment: Это у вас все в одной ячейке? Это один лейбл?

Comment: То что между Ingredients и Method одна ячейка и один UILabel

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас это `UILabel`, используйте `NSAttributedString`. Пример как поставить зеленые точки:

```
let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "•    ●", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green])
lblSomeLabel.attributedText = attrStr
```

Далее форматируете как и что Вам необходимо, а затем отображаете.